# Angular 5 DevExtreme DataGrid Widget Customize Columns

Tags: angular, datagrid, devextreme

I struggle with the caption of my columns.
I have a configurationObject where the Displayname is defined, but I'm not able to change the caption of my columns.

```html
<div class="grid">
<dx-data-grid 
    #dataGrid 
    [columnAutoWidth]="true" 
    [dataSource]='machinery' 
    (onContentReady)='onContentReady($event)'
    (onToolbarPreparing)="onToolbarPreparing($event)" 
    [showBorders]="true" 
    (onRowClick)='rowClick($event)'
    (onEditorPreparing)='onEditorPreparing($event)' 
    [customizeColumns]='customizeColumns'> 
    <dxo-remote-operations 
        sorting="true" 
        paging="true" 
        filtering="true">
    </dxo-remote-operations>
    <dxo-paging [pageSize]="50"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-scrolling mode="virtual" rowRenderingMode="virtual">
    </dxo-scrolling>
    <dxo-selection mode="single"></dxo-selection>
    <dxo-filter-row visible="true" applyFilter="auto">
    </dxo-filter-row>
    <dxi-column dataField="Company"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Sourcesystem"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Description"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

My TS Code

```js
@ViewChild('dataGrid')
_dataGrid: DxDataGridComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._dataGrid.columns.forEach(col => {
        console.log('col', col);
        col.caption = 'dd';
    });
    console.log('this._dataGrid.columns', this._dataGrid.columns);
}
```

In my example I see the changes in the console, but my captions have still the standard value.

What I'm doing wrong, or are there other solutions to change the caption of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

just give a caption property to dxi-column like below:

dxi-column alignment="left" [allowFiltering]="false" dataField="budgetUsed" caption="Budget Used"
          [allowEditing]="false" [minWidth]="400" cellTemplate="barTemplate">